# Heading tags in wordpress theme

Tags: seo, wordpress

I know we should put the website name in H1 tag and posts titles in H2 tag IN HOMEPAGE.

What about Single post pages? Which one is better?

1. Website Title in H1 and Post title in H2
2. Post title in H1 and use H2 in the content.

I think second one is better so consider this question too: Does second one worth it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 2. The reason is simple.

You are trying to rank your content on a page by page basis and not each page for your website name. That will not do you any good. Each page has to compete on it's own in the search engine result page (SERP) and that means that you must signal what is important for that page.

Follow the headline read order method where the `title` tag is the title of the page, the one and only `h1` tag supports the `title` tag but is not a duplicate of the `title` tag, and the `description` meta-tag supports both the `title` tag and `h1` tag. The `title` tag should have your top 2-3 most important keywords for your page in a conversational format. Your `h1` tag should have the same 2-3 most important keywords in a conversational format plus a few more if possible. Your `description` meta-tag should have a few more and should expand the topic understanding. As well, any other header tags, (`h2`, `h3`, `h4`, ...) should be sub-titles for each section and planned out so that other important keywords are used.

Keep in mind that your `title` tag should be about 50 characters or slightly less and if done properly, will be used for the SERP link. Your `description` meta-tag, if done right, will be used for your SERP snippet and should be 2 lines optimally. The `title` tag, `h1` tag, and any internal links and inbound back links will be used for clues by the search engine as to what your page keywords should be.

If you use your site title (as you term it) for each page, you will lose out on some valuable search users. You will be misleading them and your bounce rate will suffer. You had it right when you said option 2. Now you know why.

Answer (score 0):

The `h1` tag is the most important header on the page, it should subsequently provide the most overall and relevant heading for the content on the page.

If you were to use the name of your website/business as the `h1` on every page of your website, this is useless to a search engine and a human.

There is no science behind it, just logical structure, as with anything, like writing a book. Just make it as easy as possible for a search engine to understand your website and it's pages whilst being natural (i.e don't over think keywords in markup) - put yourself in your customers shows and write in a way that they would search.